# Yocto Clone GitLab Repo

Tags: gitlab, yocto

I can successfully build an image using code pulled from GitHub, the project will be hosted on GitLab. I have hosted the same code on GitLab but I can not get Yocto to find my repo. I have tried many things

```
SRC_URI = "git://git@gitlab.com/MichaelBMiner:~/simpledaemon_gl.git;protocol=https"
SRC_URI = "git://git@gitlab.com/MichaelBMiner:~/simpledaemon_gl.git;protocol=http"
SRC_URI = "git://git@gitlab.com/MichaelBMiner/simpledaemon_gl.git;protocol=https"
SRC_URI = "git://git@gitlab.com/MichaelBMiner/simpledaemon_gl.git;protocol=http"
SRC_URI = "git://git@gitlab.com/MichaelBMiner/simpledaemon_gl.git"
SRC_URI = "git://gitlab.com/MichaelBMiner/simpledaemon_gl.git;protocol=https"
```

I am not sure what I am missing, but nothing seems to work. I looked over the https://git.yoctoproject.org/poky/plain/bitbake/lib/bb/fetch2/git.py documentation and GitLab is supported. I cannot find any known bugs/issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SRC_URI = "git://gitlab.com/MichaelBMiner/simpledaemon_gl.git;protocol=https;branch=main"
```

Comment: I do not understand how my repo would fit into that url. My GitLab repo is also a .com

Comment: post error message?

Comment: simpledaemon-1.0+gitAUTOINC+446d9e14b5-ro do_fetch: Failed to fetch URL git://git@gitlab.com/MichaelBMiner/simpledaemon_gl.git;protocol=https

Comment: I've updated my answer with what works for me.

Comment: It seems the issue is bitbake searches for the "master" branch, I am using a "main" branch. That is very annoying but I am happy it is solved.

Comment: Hello @Oleksandr, I am facing similar issue. I am using ssh protocol instead of https. Can you please take a look at [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70856329/fetch-private-gitlab-repo-using-ssh-with-yocto-recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70856329/fetch-private-gitlab-repo-using-ssh-with-yocto-recipe)?