# Fetch private gitlab repo using ssh with Yocto recipe

Tags: ssh, embedded-linux, yocto

I am trying to fetch a private gitlab repo within Yocto image recipe using SSH protocol. In my image recipe I have passed `SRC_URI` as:

```
SRC_URI = " \
        gitsm://git@git.example.com:2224/blah/blah/blah/blah;protocol=ssh;branch=master \
"
```

But this results in the error:

```
ERROR: Fetcher failure: Fetch command export PSEUDO_DISABLED=1; export PATH="/root /build-swu-v2/tmp/sysroots-uninative/x86_64-linux/usr/bin:/root/sources/poky/scripts: /root/build-swu-v2/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/awsclient/1.4- r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi:/root/build-swu-v2/tmp /work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/awsclient/1.4-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/bin /crossscripts:/root/build-swu-v2/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi /awsclient/1.4-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/sbin:/root/build-swu-v2/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf- neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/awsclient/1.4-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin:/root/build- swu-v2/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/awsclient/1.4-r0/recipe-sysroot- native/sbin:/root/build-swu-v2/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi /awsclient/1.4-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/bin:/root/sources/poky/bitbake/bin:/root/build-swu- v2/tmp/hosttools"; export HOME="/root"; LANG=C git -c core.fsyncobjectfiles=0 clone --bare  --mirror "ssh://git@git.example.com" /root/downloads//git2/git@git.example.com:2224/blah/blah/blah/blah --progress failed with exit code 128, no output
ERROR: Bitbake Fetcher Error: FetchError('Unable to fetch URL from any source.',  'gitsm://git@git.example.com:2224/blah/blah/blah/blah;protocol=ssh;branch=master')
DEBUG: Python function base_do_fetch finished
```

But I am able to clone the repo using `git clone`.

SSH key is already added to the Gitlab. There is no config file in my `~/.ssh`. Do I need to create a config file? What should be the content of the config file?

**Update**

After following some discussion from other posts, I added "config" file.

`~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host git.example.com
HostName git.example.com
User git
PreferredAuthentications publickey
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub
# LogLevel DEBUG3
```

Then `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub`

```
Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.
```

And `ssh -T git@git.example.com`

```
ssh: connect to host git.example.com port 22: Connection refused
```

Can anyone please let me know how to resolve this?

Thanks in advance.

P.S: I am using Ubuntu 20.04 with Yocto on Dunfell version.

Comment: Your ssh key is not accepted. Fix it first.

Comment: Are you adding ssh key on the wrong side or something? Talk to the person who admins git server.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this? I am now having the same issue

Comment: Hello @Michael, no I didn't find time to further investigate. You may find something useful [here](https://lists.yoctoproject.org/g/yocto/topic/fetch_private_gitlab_repo/88691891?p=,,,20,0,0,0::recentpostdate/sticky,,,20,2,0,88691891,previd=1643367006876978120,nextid=1643156766212817620&previd=1643367006876978120&nextid=1643156766212817620). I didn't try out these things yet. Please let me know what worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
SRC_URI = "git://git.example.com:2224/blah/blah.git;protocol=ssh;branch=master"
```

Comment: Hi @Oleksandr, yes I am trying to fix ssh. I tried with Port 443 also. When I did `ssh -v git@git.blah.com` I get `debug1: /root/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for git.blah.com
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to git.blah.com [116.203.241.118] port 443.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 type 3`

Comment: `debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
debug1: kex_exchange_identification: banner line 0: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
debug1: kex_exchange_identification: banner line 1: Server: nginx
kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host`

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem and it is as follows.

My test application is called simpledaemon.
I deleted sources/meta-simpledaemon
I ran the following bitbake commands

```
bitbake-layers create-layer ../sources/meta-simpledaemon
bitbake-layers add-layer ../sources/meta-simpledaemon
mkdir ../sources/meta-simpledaemon/recipes-example/simpledaemon
recipetool create -V 1.0 git@gitlab.com:MichaelBMiner/simpledaemon.git -o ../sources/meta-simpledaemon/recipes-example/simpledaemon/
```

Now the problem I had was GitLab be default names your primary branch `main`, recipe by default looks for `master`. So I made my primary branch name master and it all worked!